# Modal / Pop-up window does not appear in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a page that when you visit the site, a modal / dialog window appears. However, when I am running it via Cypress, it does not seem to appear on the runner.
Sample code:

```
cy.visit('http://demo-site.com')
cy.get('[id="modal"]').invoke('show') // This works so it seems the element can be found.
.get('[id="ok-button"]').click(); // This does not work as this is an element inside the modal
```

Snippet of the element console:

```
<div id="modal">
 <div class="modal-container">
  <div class="ui-container">
   <div class="ui-mask ui-mask-is-active" aria-hidden="false">
    <section class="ui-modal ui-modal-layout" tabindex="0" role="dialog">
     <footer class="ui-modal--footer ui-actions ui-actions-layout">
      <button id="ok-button" type="button">OK</button>
     </footer>
    </section>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Note: I have checked this blog but the problem is the calendar modal appears here while on mine, it does not: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click/

Answer (score -3):

It might be a timing issue.

To help cypress find the modal you should add a wait command like this:

```
cy.wait(500);
```

Here is a full example

```
cy.visit('http://demo-site.com')
cy.url().should("equal", 'http://demo-site.com');
cy.contains("btn").click({
        force: false
});
cy.wait(500);
```

This will wait for 500ms after you simulate a click on a button that shows the modal. This allows the modal to appear on screen.